# PDO Success message not firing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Trying to find out why a success or failure message is not displayed

I do the following in a class inside a php file

```
 public  $errors                   = array();    
 public  $messages                 = array();
```

...

```
public function yyyy(xxxx)
$this->db_connection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
            $query_user_update = $this->db_connection->prepare('UPDATE users SET user_email = :user_email, user_type = :user_type WHERE id = :id');                                              
            $query_user_update->bindValue(':user_email', $user_email, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
            $query_user_update->bindValue(':user_type', $user_type, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
            $query_user_update->bindValue(':id', $_SESSION['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);             
            $query_user_update->execute();  
            $count = $query_user_update->rowCount();
```

I used $count to show me if the row was updated This is only used for debugging to make sure I have updated at least 1 row. I then do the following:

```
  if ($query_user_update) { 
                    // Set to true so the page does not reload the form
                    $this->updateuser_successful = true;  
                    // Display success message
                    $this->messages[] = MESSAGE_USERRECORD_CHANGED_SUCCESSFULLY;                                              
                    print("We Have Updated $count rows.\n");                                      
           } else {
                // display failure message
                $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_USERRECORD_CHANGED_FAILED;
           }
```

I have included the file that contains all my messages by using the require_once('en.php) in the php page that loads the form.

When this is run and I update the record in a form and submit, $count is 1 as the message "We Have Updated 1 row" is displayed on the screen but the message assigned to MESSAGE_USERRECORD_CHANGED_SUCCESSFULLY is not. I check the database and I can also see that the record was indeed updated.

I have another form where this works so I am a bit puzzled. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You didn't include the class that this code fragment comes from, but I can't help but wonder what happens to `$this->messages`-- does it echo itself out to the browser, or does it rely on other code to do that? Maybe in the other file you are echoing `$this->messages` out, but in this page you forgot to?

Comment: You both helped me. I have a _header.php file that I include on all my forms. in this file I echo the success and error messages amongst other items. I forgot to echo this class messages. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not returned or echoed.

```
if ($query_user_update) { 
                    // Set to true so the page does not reload the form
                    $this->updateuser_successful = true;  
                    // Display success message
                    $this->messages[] = MESSAGE_USERRECORD_CHANGED_SUCCESSFULLY;                                              
                    print("We Have Updated $count rows.\n");    
                    return $this->messages;                                  
           } else {
                // display failure message
                $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_USERRECORD_CHANGED_FAILED;
                return $this->errors;
           }
```

You now do this in the page where your form is:

```
$returnData = $someClass->someFunction(params);
for($i = 0; $i < count($returnData); $i++) {
    echo $returnData[$i];
}
```

The $returnData variable holds the returned array, which is either the errors or messages.

Comment: See my response above.. you and the other commenter pointed me in the right direction. I simply forgot to echo the values as you stated.

Comment: Yes. I spotted it out and answered it